# Displaying a placeholder for null values

Tags: visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

When a value is null, I don't want it to display as a blank. Instead, I want there to be some kind of default value like "N/A". How can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a formula field to detect the null value.

```
If IsNull({Product.Description}) then
"Not available"
else
{Product.Description}
```

Cheers

Comment: i want to know where to put this formula ?

Comment: In the 'field explorer' panel, create a new 'formula field' with the previous code. Then replace your database field with the field you just created.

Comment: What is the problem? The formula works but it's not producing the expected result? Need more details.